# find and ls output

Tags: linux, scripting, find, ls

I am having trouble trying to output all my .mp4 films into a text file, it works but there are a few quirky things occurring and I am not sure why.

Here is the cmd.

```
find "/volume1 HD FILMS" -iname "*.mp4" -type f -exec ls {} \; > "/volume1/3. HD FILMS/HD_FILMS_`date +%d.%m.%Y`.txt"
```

1. why is it outputting the path? when an ls inside the directory just prints the file (which is what I want)
2. why is the output file, not in alphabetical order (again compare to an ls inside the dir - it seems random)

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact questions:

> why is it outputting the path? when an ls inside the directory just prints the file (which is what I want)

It's outputting the path because you're *not* inside the directory.  `ls somedir` is different from `cd somedir; ls`.

> why is the output file, not in alphabetical order (again compare to an ls inside the dir - it seems random)

`ls` puts files in alphabetical order and then outputs them *all*.  So it has an opportunity to sort them before printing them.

When you use `find` with `-exec` and terminate the command with `\;`, you are explicitly telling `find` to run one command (in this case one `ls` command) for *every* file found by `find`.  Thus there is no possibility to sort them.

If you used `ls -l` you would also notice that the columns were not aligned correctly, since each printed line is actually output from a different command.

Instead, you could consider using `find ... -ls` or `find ... -print`, or if it's really necessary to use `-exec ls`, **you could use `-exec ls {} +`**, which should handle the sorting for the most part.  (Specifically, it is likely to sort all files together, but if there is such a large number that it exceeds your system's `ARG_MAX`, then `find` will be forced to use separate `ls` commands and those separate batches will be sorted separately.)

---

**Note:** I personally would never save such a list of filenames into a text file, because filenames *can* contain newlines.  There is no foolproof way to parse a text file into individual file names.  Period.  (See [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943))

Instead, I would just run the `find` command *when I wanted to do something* with the files, not run it in advance and then try to do something with the earlier output.

If I wanted to generate a human readable list of all my `mp4` files, I would emphasize that these can NOT be relied on as filenames by stripping out the path components:

```
find "/volume1 HD FILMS" -iname "*.mp4" -type f -print | sed 's:.*/::;s/\.[mM][pP]4$//' > "/volume1/3. HD FILMS/HD_FILMS_$(date +%d.%m.%Y).txt"
```

Comment: ok great, i will give this a try, appreciate i the assistance and clarification!